# Haskell IO action in `StateT a STM b`

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad, stm, io-monad

I want to run `randomIO` inside my `StateT a STM b` but I get this error:

```hs
Expected type: StateT Session STM Float
  Actual type: IO Float
```

so I try `lift`'ing from `Control.Monad.Trans.Class` (re-exported by State's Strict module):

```hs
Expected type: StateT Session STM Float
  Actual type: StateT Session IO Float
```

which is closer but not quite there. I can't `liftIO` because there's no `MonadIO` instance for `STM`.

How can I get this to compile so I can run `randomIO` inside `STM` inside my `StateT`?

Comment: Well the Monad transformer wraps around an `STM Float`, not an `IO Float`.

Comment: You can't run IO actions inside STM, not even `randomIO`. You need to find a workaround, like pre-generating your random numbers before entering STM, or passing the RNG state around in STM.

Comment: You can use `unsafeIOToSTM`, but as the name indicates: that is unsafe, and therefore you better do not do this.

Comment: related: https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2007-January/021330.html

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, it might be okay in some contexts. If the random number selected doesn't affect the probability that the transaction will succeed, then it should be perfectly fine. I'd it does affect that, then it'll modify the effective distribution, which may or may not be acceptable. That said, random number generation likely takes longer than you really want to spend in an STM transaction.

Comment: Given I'm passing in the list from the `random` package, what is the effect of laziness in this scenario when the STM transaction "pulls" a value? Is passing a thunk dangerous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments I was attempting something stupid. Instead I passed a list of random `Float`s that I needed to my function using `randomRs (0.0, 1.0) g`.